# How to get the selected item index from the listview in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin

Here i want to display the selected item index in Xamarin Forms listview in below code iam getting InvalidCastException in e.SelectedItemIndex.

```
 private async void animelist_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var si = (Applications)animelist.SelectedItem;
            string i = Convert.ToString(e.SelectedItemIndex);
            await DisplayAlert("Info",i,"Ok");
        }
```

Comment: `string i = e.SelectedItemIndex.ToString();`

Comment: Yeah I tried but again it shows the exception 

Comment: are you sure the exception is not on the first line where you are actually doing a cast?  Have you checked in the debugger?

Comment: Nope I commented that line and tried again but it result in exception again

Comment: what is the value of SelectedItemIndex?

Comment: It should return an integer value of the index of the selected item in the list view but when I tap an item in the list view the app crashes

Comment: use the debugger to check the value

Comment: Thanks I made a mistake the error is in first line I changed the applications class to another class name in my code and now it works!

Comment: @user11640506 Can you share your solution here and mark it as answer, or  your can mark the helpful post as answer, it is beneficial to others to find answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's is a code snippet that works for me and I believe should work for you.

```
 //change Core.Models.Data.TaskItem to the object you want to cast to.
 var SelectedItem = (Core.Models.Data.TaskItem)e.SelectedItem;

 await DisplayAlert("Info", $"{SelectedItem.Description}}", "Ok");
 //where SelectedItem.Description is a field in my model
```

The reason you got an invalid cast exception is that **animelist.SelectedItem** is of type ListView.SelectedItem and you're trying to cast it **Application** type. Using e.SelectedItem as shown in the sample will take on the generic type of your listView binding model.

Let me know if this helps.